# Multi select html inserting multi values into database

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter, html-select

I'm working on a category section for stories submitted to my website. I have a html select going on in my html and I have that submitting to the database using codeigniter functions. It is submitting to the database, but there seems to be a small problem...the select is only grabbing the last value that is selected. I need to have all the values that are selected entered into the database so I can pull them out at a later date.

This is the html I am using.

```
<select multiple class="multi" name="wGenre">
                  <option value="Action/Adventure">Action/Adventure</option>                      <option value="Angst">Angst</option>
                  <option value="Crime">Crime</option>
</select>
```

and then this is what I have in my model.

```
$this->title = $this->input->post('wTitle');    
$this->genre = $this->input->post('wGenre');    
$this->db->insert('story_tbl', $this);
```

Now, I believe the problem is with my database. I originally set up the field as an enum, but that won't work because it's either one or the other selection and I need to have multiples. So then I tried it as a text field, and it's just not grabbing everything. To be honest I'm at a loss and in need of some help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this without a foreach loop.

First of all, I was writting my html select tag wrong. For it to select multiple values you have to add both [] at the end of the class and a muti tag...like this.

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi" name="wGenre[]">
```

and then in the php it has to be json encoded to be placed in the database correctly...like this...

```
$this->genre = json_encode($this->input->post('wGenre'));
```

Thank you for all your help! I hope this helps someone else in the future! :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to make sure the select tag is named the array manner:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multi" name="wGenre[]">
```

Then To get all values of the multiple select you could do the following to save the values in an array!

```
$this->title = $this->input->post('wTitle');    
$select_vals = array();
foreach($this->input->post('wGenre') as $val){
    $val.' - '; // Used as a delimiter for later use
    array_push($select_vals, $val);
}
$this->genre = $select_vals;    
$this->db->insert('story_tbl', $this);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It seems that the foreach was not constructed properly. I tried switching the $select_vals  $this->input->post('wGenre') to see if that would work. and it did, but it's still only saving the last value and not all the values